# Flip single list item on a click and get detailed description on back of that item

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, flipview

I am having problem in animation of a single list item. how can i get the flip view upon click on the single item and get the detail on back of the item?

Comment: This an incomplete question. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create your list row item as below

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/rellay"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linearlayoutshape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="BACK"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" 
   />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/linearlayoutshape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="FRONT"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large" />
```

In this case i used to textView as Front and Back.
Now inside your adapter add this method..

```
public void flip(final View front, final View back, final int duration) 
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playSequentially(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(front, "rotationY", 90).setDuration(duration / 2),
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(front, "visibility", View.GONE).setDuration(0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(back, "rotationY", -90).setDuration(0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(back, "visibility", View.VISIBLE).setDuration(0),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(back, "rotationY", 0).setDuration(duration / 2));
        set.start();
    } else
    {
        front.animate().rotationY(90).setDuration(duration / 2)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        front.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        back.setRotationY(-90);
                        back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        back.animate().rotationY(0).setDuration(duration / 2).setListener(null);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Now on click of row item just call flip method like

```
flip(txtFront, txtBack, DURATION);
```

It will add the flip animation and make txtBack visible and hide the txtFront

Comment: forgot to call start() on the ViewPropertyAnimator?